# WYSIWYG HTML / CSS builder

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface

Maybe it is to much to ask...

I want to make a online WYSIWYG HTML / CSS builder where the graphic designer can build a website template without knowing CSS /HTML. For that purpose there should be a GUI to build a website template.

That means HTML and CSS are created out of the choices selected in the GUI.

http://www.constructyourcss.com kinda does what I want. But I can't set width/height etc + I need to integrate it into my system (I use PHP, MySQL,jQuery)

Question:
Do you know any html/css builder tools like ala jquery sortables?

Comment: I'd approach this from a different angle: what makes you think a graphic designer would use your tool over Photoshop or Dreamweaver?

Comment: Because they already made it in photoshop. Now the y want to implement it without having extensive knowledge in CSS / HTML

Comment: I read this 3 times and I still don't see a question.

Comment: @Cudos: Any web designer with respect for himself would consider knowing HTML/CSS a must. Even if there are plenty of UI frameworks already.

Comment: @Cudos If they made it in Photoshop, they can slice and export it. It will be crap HTML, but the graphic designers I know are not exactly known to care about valid markup. Besides, there is services that can turn PSD files into valid HTML. Not wanting to discourage you though, but I think it's wasted time (at least when targeted at graphic designers)

Comment: I agree. It is a fantastic exercise to improve your skills by building this kind of framework. But as far as business case goes, doesn't look promising. At least, rethink your target group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any online tools, but I really like the way this standalone program called [Stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/) enables users who don't know CSS very well to modify web site layouts. But honestly, there's no way I'd pay $89 for it. I recommended it to some friends to use it for the trial period, but learn how to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as well.

That being said, I tend to agree with the comments above. A designer is more likely to learn CSS/HTML and do it themselves or pay a service to convert their pdf into a page.